# DEBIAN Wireless connection error: SIOCSIFADDR: No such device

Tags: wireless-networking, debian

I'm trying to connect via wifi but i keep getting this message: (I'm using NO interface)

> SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
>
> wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
>
> wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
>
> Bind socket to interface: No such device
>
> Failed to bring up wlan0.

I've already edited the interfaces file on /etc/networks adding this line:

> auto wlan0
>
> iface wlan0 inet dhcp

and i cannot scan using "iwlist wlan0 scan"

How can I make this a Wi-Fi Client?

> I'm using Debian GNU/Linux 6.0

wlan0 doesn't appear in the ifconfig -a output that is:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:ad:4e:00:da:29  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:11 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:50:43:4a:8c:9b  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:15 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:146 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:146 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:14127 (13.7 KiB)  TX bytes:14127 (13.7 KiB)

pan0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:1f:77:39:8d:28  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

uap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:23:78:08:69  
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::224:23ff:fe78:869/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:604 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:219 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:49186 (48.0 KiB)  TX bytes:18142 (17.7 KiB)
```

Comment: Does a `wlan0` interface show up in `ifconfig` output?

Comment: nope. it doesn't. Here's my ifconfig output:

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: If the link is down, you won't see it in plain old `ifconfig`. Try `ifconfig -a`. Also, you didn't indicate your *exact* wireless hardware (try `lspci -nnvv`) which is crucial to know anything about how to answer this question. We also need to know which version of Debian from `/etc/issue` file. Also, if you are needing WEP or WPA support, you should use NetworkManager; all other methods of using the wifi stack are spotty at best.

Comment: Is this info usefull? 

IEEE 802.11-DS  ESSID:"dream-uAP-0869"  
          Mode:Master  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 00:24:23:78:08:69   
          Encryption key:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

Comment: @user1911133: Master mode ? you took these info from your AP right ? but we need info about the client. What card is it, what driver does it uses (Debian 6.0's kernel is rather old, if you ask, unless you use backports) and what is the interface name...

Comment: I've tryed with commands like `lspci -nn` and `lspci -nn -s 0c:00.0` but i get no output. And the info of my last comment was taken from the client that I want to connect to my AP .. or how else can I get this info? the card and driver ? ..

Comment: Hey. I think i'm almost there. i can now see the AP with the `iwconfig`command, but now when i try to connect to it using: `iwconfig mlan0 essid NETWORK_ID key WIRELESS_KEY` i get the following error:

Error for wireless request "Set ESSID" (8B1A) :
    SET failed on device mlan0 ; Bad address.


... what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Get your computer connected to the internet using the Ethernet cable, then from your terminal, choose which of the Debian distribution you prefer and run the `deb http.....`, after choosing which of the debian distribution you wanna get your update from run continue to no **2**

## 1

- Debian 9 "Stretch"

`deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free`

- Debian 8 "Jessie"

`deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free`

- For Debian 7 "Wheezy"

`deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free`

## 2

Update the list of available packages and install the firmware-iwlwifi package by running: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi`

## 3

As the iwlwifi module is automatically loaded for supported devices, reinsert this module to access installed firmware: `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi ; modprobe iwlwifi`

After which you might want to reboot your computer then run `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`

I hope this helps